# Website containing a list of usernames what can be added by anyone

Tags: list, web

So I had this idea to make a website for giveaways in League of Legends. 
It would work like this:

- Anyone can sign up for giveaway. No registration required.
- There is only one page with input field and submit button.
- You input a username in the field and submit it, adding it to the list.
- The list is also shown at the bottom of the page and downloadable as a text file.

I'm kind of a new to websites and I don't know where to start. All the places that host webpages for free only use templates which do not allow me to make something like this.

Also, do I need to know anything other than HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should know at least 1 programming language. PHP,ASP&C#. You can Use A Textfile to save Usernames and show it and every1 can downloadit .also you can use Database To keep Usernames .